# How to make Redis automatically handle persistent connection with Predis

Tags: php, redis, gearman, predis

I'm using `predis` to interact with two Redis instances (master and slave servers). Master is mainly for write only and slave is used for read only.

I'm having to switch connections using `select` function of `Redis` which is fine but I'm concerned about its performance. Would I be better off to create a singleton class and use it for instantiating `$this->redis` and also for `select` how would I maintain persistence?

Below is bits of my code so far. I was wondering if this could be done to increase performance?

```
$redis = $this->redis;

$tipperKey = str_pad($tipperId, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
if ($this->debug) {
  $this->logger->addDebug('tipperKey=' . $tipperKey);
  $this->logger->addDebug("Adding groupId:$groupId to \"groups:$tipperKey\" in db:0");
}

// add groupId to tipper groups set
try {
  $redis->select(0);
  $redis->sadd('groups:' . $tipperKey, $groupId);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $this->logger->addError("Error adding groupId:$groupId to \"groups:$tipperKey\" in db:0 : " . $e->getMessage());
  return false;
}

$result = $this->getRoundsPlayed($competitionId); // cached (600)
if (!$result) {
  return false;
}

$tk = 'tipper:' . $tipperKey;
try {
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $i = (int)$row['round_number'];
    if ($this->debug) {
      $this->logger->addDebug('select db:' . $i);
    }
    $redis->select($i);

    $sportId = (int)$row['sport_id'];
```

BTW, this is for Gearman Job

Comment: There is something I don't understand. You say you are using select to switch between the connections. But Redis select command switches the current database in a Redis instance, it has nothing to do with the connection. Did I miss anything?

Comment: In a way is there a way to increase performance of this part and maintain persistent connection?

Comment: The code you posted above is incomplete (the end of the foreach loop is missing). It does not help to understand what you want to do...